# Spring-Boot: Specify REALMs (security constraints and roles) and CLIENT-CERT authentication in Java code configuration (not XML)?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security, spring-boot

I've been trying to get CLIENT-CERT realm authentication to work based on the following link:

http://twoguysarguing.wordpress.com/2009/11/03/mutual-authentication-with-client-cert-tomcat-6-and-httpclient/

However, despite using the following `web.xml`,

```
<web-app>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Demo App</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>secureconn</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
  <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Demo App</realm-name>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
  <role-name>secureconn</role-name>
  </security-role>
</web-app>
```

And for HTTPS to work in general I used the following link:

http://thoughtfulsoftware.wordpress.com/2014/01/05/setting-up-https-for-spring-boot/

And thus I have something like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

  @Bean
  public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
      TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
      factory.addContextCustomizers((TomcatContextCustomizer) customizer ->
      {
         //this is empty at the moment
      });


      factory.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer) (Connector con) -> {
         //...configuration
      });
      return factory;
```

And I also have this to enable Spring Security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     //...some configuration from the sample at https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/
  }
  ...
}
```

It seems to me that the embedded Tomcat *doesn't really care* about the `web.xml` content, so I'm guessing I need to configure this from Java, possibly using the `Context Customizer`. I've found no resources on doing this whatsoever and most parameters are **String**, so I'm guessing I'm either doing something terribly wrong, or it's just not documented, or I'm looking at the wrong place.

So my question is,

http://java.boot.by/wcd-guide/ch05s03.html

**How should one specify realms, security contraints, and login configurations / authentication method / url-pattern with Spring-Boot, if not with the web.xml?**

Alternative question,

**If it is possible to make the embedded Tomcat in Spring Boot use web.xml, how is that done?**

EDIT: Actually, considering I'm trying to use **CLIENT-CERT** auth method, this might be `httpSecurity.x509()` which has even less samples... I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample using certificate-based authentication at the container level: https://github.com/SpringOne2GX-2014/microservice-security/tree/master/certs (it's more about stuff that would live in server.xml than in web.xml in a non-embedded container). That app is secure. If you add a `WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter` and call `http.x509()` you will also get the authenticated principal turned into an `Authentication` and made available in the usual places for Spring Security.

Comment: While this has been accepted, it does not actually answer the question of how to set up a "CLIENT-CERT" authentication method but instead illustrates how to implement with "clientAuth = need".